# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space on EntitySave

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-9

I know what this error means, the unusual thing it whats throwing it.

```
EntitySave(arguments.entity);
```

gives me a

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

why?

note: there are no dumps nor anything else throwing this error.

Comment: There is very little information to go on here.  I am not familiar with ColdFusion, but understand that it uses java under the hood.  If you can figure out how to modify the java startup options for coldfusion, you can use the -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError option to get more information.  See: http://blogs.opcodesolutions.com/roller/java/entry/solve_java_lang_outofmemoryerror_java

Comment: Take a look at C:\ColdFusion9\runtime\logs\cfusion-out.log. There may be a full stack trace there to hint at what was running at the time.

Comment: Looking at the stack trace will help, but you could help *us* by including: a) whether it's saving ANY entity or a specific type; b) if the latter, the model for said entity; c) any other troubleshooting steps you've performed, and if you've got a repro case to share.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, found the answer. Sorry I did not give a lot of information still new to ORM and did not know how to view logs.

Anyhow what I found is that 'out of memory' only happened on 'insert'. looking at my entity I included a  preInsert() function, in this function I had...

```
if(structKeyExists(this,"SETCREATEDBY")){
  local.accountuser = getService("accountService").getAccountLoggedIn();
  writeDump(this);
                this.setcreatedBy(local.accountuser); 

}
```

So yes my bad I did have a dump!!!! So sorry for wasting your time a lesson learned I promise! :)

Comment: Remember when dumping entities to add a top:n to your writeDump's eg. `writeDump(var:this,top:2,abort:true);`